# Thread issue in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to generate a random fruit and display it on GUI in a label. I am using this code to do it.

```
 partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    int MagicNumber = 0;
    List<string> NameList = new List<string>();
    Random r = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameList.Add("Apples");
        NameList.Add("Pears");
        NameList.Add("Oranges");
        NameList.Add("Bananas");
        NameList.Add("Kiwi");

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Display));
            t.Start();

            label1.Text = NameList[MagicNumber];
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
   }

    private void Display()
    {
        MagicNumber = r.Next(5);
    }
}
```

The problem is the fact that in GUI i see only the last result of fruits choice and not how they are skipped from an iteration to other. I thought that this code will give me the possibility to see how fruits changes until the last was chosen , when i is 8.

Please if you have an idea why this code is not displaying how the fruits are chosen in label give me a hand !

Thanks.

Comment: You only do the random number generation in a separate thread (with a race condition when accessing it), you lock the UI with your Thread.Sleep so you'll only see the last result, you need to move your code in Display() and then you'll have to call Control.Invoke to access UI thread from the new thread

Comment: it looks like you try to do C style threading, it's different in C#

Comment: Starting a new thread just to set the value of a single int is really, really ineffective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `Application.DoEvents();` after assigning text to label - that will refresh UI.

BTW I don't understand why you are using threads to generate random numbers

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing timers and threads. In this case, I think what you want is a timer; specifically, [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). You might do something like this:

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
   Timer timer = new Timer();

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      int i = 0;

      timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
      {
         if (i < 8)
         {
               label1.Text = nameList[r.Next(5)];
               i++;
         }
         else
            timer.Stop();
      };

      timer.Interval = 1000;
      timer.Start();
   }
}
```

The idea is that you set a timer to tick once a second, and then each time it ticks, you change the label and increment the counter until it reaches  8 -- at which point it stops. You always want to make sure you call `Start()` *after* you've set `Tick` and `Interval`; otherwise, under some strange circumstances, the timer might tick before you have a chance to change the settings.

Alternatively, you could use threading and Sleep(), in which case it might look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Display));
   t.Start();
}

private void Display()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
      label1.Text = NameList[r.Next(5)];
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
}
```

`Thread.Sleep()` always sleeps the thread that it's called from -- so maybe this is what you meant to do.

However, this might throw a thread synchronization exception -- Forms prevents you from accessing UI controls from another thread, since it might be in an invalid state (i.e. in the middle of rendering or doing something else that's volatile). System.Windows.Forms.Timer actually runs on the UI thread, so it's easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is flawed, but you may want to understand what is going on in your code, as it may help you find a better approach:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Display));
        t.Start();

        label1.Text = NameList[MagicNumber];
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
```

You are looking through, creating eight threads every time the button is clicked.  Do you have a reason to create eight threads?  If so, you may want to create them once, inside your `init` function and reuse them.

Then there is a race here in that your threads may not have had time to change `MagicNumber` before it is used, as the loop starts the threads then immediately changes the text, before going to sleep.

The sleep is another problem, as you haven't gotten off of the main (event) thread, so the text isn't changed until you exit that event handler.

If you want to see the text changing, then you will need to get off of the main thread, and in a second thread go through and do the loop of eight.

Then, you can put that thread to sleep, and since the main thread was free to make the change you will see it.

Here is an article from MS that is a bit dated, but the basic idea should help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188732.aspx

Now you can use lambda expressions for your threads, as shown here:

http://www.rvenables.com/2009/01/threading-tips-and-tricks/

Answer (score 0):

Your observed problem of the form not refreshing is due to your function blocking the GUI thread and preventing a redraw of the window while its running. And it's continuously running for 8 seconds. The GUI thread needs to handle messages to allow a window to be redrawn.

But apart from what you observed it has has at least two theoretical problems related to threading:

1. The read of MagicNumber isn't volatile, so the compiler may read it only once and cache the result. It probably won't do that in practice since the code between each reading of the variable is so complicated that it can't guarantee that they won't affect the variable.
2. `r.Next` isn't threadsafe. So calling it from two different threads at the same time can corrupt the `Random` instance. Won't happen in practice either since the delay is so long that one thread will most likely have finished before the next one starts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you execute an event handler or a function called from it, the changes are rendered at the end. Try changhing the label text inside the thread where you get the random number. You also have to set the CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls property to false in the form constructor.

Comment: You may only change the label text from the GUI thread. And just because you can disable the exception waring you that you're doing something wrong doesn't make it right.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - the entire event handler code should be off the GUI thread ASAP, and in a secondary thread the label can be changed and it would be noticeable, so this answer isn't wrong, just poorly worded.

Comment: "It is unsafe to call a control from a thread other than the one that created the control without using the Invoke method." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Comment: Sometimes you want to do ethically-right application, and sometimes you just want them to work. Of course, everyone is free to spend hours to solve simple problems!

Comment: Sometimes you want to do randomly crashing application, and sometimes you want them to work.

Comment: @CodeInChaos - You can use Invoke: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx, but nowadays with the Parallel Framework Extension you can do away with the delegate and get this to work reliably.

Comment: It is unsafe, but what is the probability of a crash? I would just decide if the gained stability is worth my additional work. Usually I don't like to waste my time, even if it is what I am doing now!

Answer (score -2):

There is a much better way to choose a random item:

```
label1.Text = NameList.OrderBy(f => Guid.NewGuid()).First();
```

Randomizing on different threads is a bad idea in of itself.

Comment: O_O do you know the performance cost of NewGuid?? why not just random?

Comment: This technique is from Jeff Atwood. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html

Comment: this technique could be from Donald Knuth, it's still dumb, and expensive without any reason.

Comment: In Jeff's original example it makes more sense then here. Since writing a correct shuffle isn't that easy. But I'd still use a crypto PRNG instead of creating a guid to get unpredictable numbers.

Comment: And I see no indication in the documentation of `NewGuid` about how the Guid is generated. While kind 4 Guids are random, there are other guids generation methods which don't result in random numbers.